# Баг скроллинга в чате (на моб.устройстве)

Tags: height

Помогите найти и устранить ошибку.
При отправке сообщения, чат скроллится в самый конец и через секунду случается скачек на 4-5 сообщения вверх и последние отправленные уже не видно. Не знаю в чем может быть причина. По хорошему, чат должен скроллится в конец к последнему сообщению и на нем фиксироваться.

С ПК вроде все нормально отображается, а вот с мобильного устройства замечаются скачки и смещение сообщений.

[Прикладываю видео с багом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytq17UnTXxM)

[Исходники чата](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4j3U/3k3moM4K8)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    border: solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div class="block">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Comment: Так-то оно так) я это пробовал и ранее, но если в блоке 2 строчки с текстом, то все норм, но если в блоках 8 строчек и более, то эти блоки с сообщениями начинают скакать по высоте, происходит небольшой скроллинг в окне чата (если зайти с мобильного устройства). А когда задаешь фиксированную высоту, тогда все отлично. В общем лучше видео записать, чтоб наглядно показать суть проблемы.